# Terraform ec2 instance with dependency on ebs volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using terraform to provision infrastructure via aws.
I have an autoscaling group which has a mixed instance policy as below

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "solr_asg" {

  mixed_instances_policy {
      launch_template {
        launch_template_specification {
          launch_template_id = foo
          version            = bar
        }
        override {
          instance_type = var.instance_type
          launch_template_specification {
            launch_template_id = foo
            version            = bar
        }
        override {
         ....
        }
      } 
  }
}
```

Along with this, we provision an ebs volume per ec2 instance with a lambda that attaches the ebs volume to the instance on startup. Lamdba is not included here

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "storage" {
  count = <<instance.count>>

  availability_zone = foo.az
  size              = foo
  type              = bar
  throughput        = baz

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

}
```

When I'm creating my infra, or scaling my cluster up by adding nodes, terraform apply works fine, However when I want to scale down the cluster terraform apply gets stuck in a loop. It first attempts to destroy the ebs volume but get's hung at this step - reason being it cannot destroy the ebs volume as it is attached to the running ec2 instance. I have to manually kill the instance before the ebs volume can be destroyed.
I've tried adding `depends_on` to the ebs volume to the launch tempalte, but that didn't work. If I try to add it to the asg,  I get

```
Error: Cycle: module.solr.aws_ebs_volume.storage, module.solr.aws_autoscaling_group.solr_asg
```

By default, I do not want the ebs volume deleted on termination as we have lambda functions that detach the ebs volume when an instance goes down and auto re-attaches it to a new instance when provisioned in the case of a node getting killed by the asg or whatever other reason. In these cases we want to preserve the data.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm looking for with terraform? Can anyone spot what I'm missing?